# proving subset is a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

prove that the subset is
a vector subspace

How do I prove this? I suspect it is false but dont know how to show it
- The set of all $2 × 2$ matrices of determinant $≥ 0$

Again I am not sure for this one
- The set of all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(1)\cdot p(4) = 0$

Comment: Do you know the properties needed for something to be called a vector space?  It must satisfy that if you take two things in the set and you add them, it is again in the set.  It must satisfy that if you take a thing in the set and multiply it by a number from your scalar field (in this case a real number) it is again in the set.  Is it true that if you take two matrices with non-negative determinant and add them that the resulting matrix also has non-negative determinant?  (*Hint: $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-9\end{bmatrix}$ has determinant equal to $9$*)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The only 'linear' condition is the middle one (if as I suspect it is an integral that should vanish). In the first and in the third you should look for counter examples (it is not difficult to find).

Comment: The 2nd is a vector space. Recall that you need to show that given any two elements, say $f$ and $g$  in the space and reals $a,b$ then $af+bg$ should also be in the space.  In the first case note that the condition is that $\det M=ad -bc\geq 0$ (for the 'usual' 2 by 2 matrix). So try to find two matrices that verify this but such that their sum does not. (similar approach in the last example)

Answer (score 1):

Are you from Macquarie University? I am doing 133 too and these exact questions are in the Assignment. Thats not cool...

1. You can show this by a counter example.
2. Think about it.
3. You can show this by a counter example. Hint: $(x-1)$ and $(x-4)$